Register ConfigConnector created cluster in ArgoCD
I am trying to setup an environment with GKE, ConfigConnector and ArgoCD.
I have management cluster where I installed ArgoCD and ConfigConnector. Then I use ConfigConnector to create a new GKE cluster in different project. As a result I following resources in the management cluster:

namespace argocd with entire Argo installation
namespace foo configured to store all ConfigConnector resources in another project
namespace foo has ContainerCluster object represeting cluster in foo project (let's call it bar)

Now, ContainerCluster named bar has within spec information required for connection (spec.masterAuth.clusterCaCertificate and spec.privateClusterConfig.publicEndpoint).
To register this cluster as manager cluster in my ArgoCD instance I need to create a secret in argocd namespace. How can I ensure it gets populated with values from my bar object in foo namespace?
